# Gravity is really low when animation is added to a character

Tags: unity

Basically I added a animation to my character, applied root motion so he could move around, although the gravity somehow decreased alot, my character now descends slowly...

Comment: Try adding a "GravityWeight" curve with a value of 1.0 to your animations.

Comment: sometimes having the parents position accidently keyed into the animation can make it slowly descend as you describe and it would also override the gravity settings since the parents position is recorded to move over time. If the "gravity weight" doesn't help I would double check that next.